# What's the difference from "Standard VM" and "MacOS X VM" in installed JREs in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

As following picture display:
[image]

What's the difference from "Standard VM" and "MacOS X VM"?
And is it better that just install one version JDK(1.8.0_60)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MacOS X VM** : Apple implementation

**Standard VM** : Oracle (previously Sun) implementation

Just choose one for your local development.

Comment: Hi Himalay, is "MacOS X VM" installed on Mac by default when we bought the MacBook laptop?

Comment: Which one VM do you suggest to use? Thank you.

Comment: Either should work fine for you. If you don't need Java 1 backward compatibility (which I am pretty sure you don't), I would go with MacOS X VM.